# VS2012 Publish Profiles - Encrypted Password

Tags: continuous-integration, visual-studio-2012, publish-profiles

I've loved using the new VS 2012 Publishing Profiles, but when using them on a build server i'm unsure how to store the password.

When I tick the box the "save the password" it creates a .pubxml.user file and encrypts the password in an XML node.

When i run the deployment on a build server the password file always seems to be ignored.

I can get away with storing the password in a

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Password>NotMyRealPassword>
</PropertyGroup
```

But given they are already encrypting it i'd love to use the VS Encryption if I can.

How do i unecrypt and fill the `<Password>` property without building a custom task to do so?

Also - if I did have to build a custom MSBUILD task, what type of encryption is in use in this SUO file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I was trying to write an answer to your question I realized that I'm not well suited to answer the quetsion, but I did want to make some comments on the .pubxml.user file.

When you save a web publish profile in Visual Studio we encrypt the password and store the encrypted value in the .pubxml.user file for the given publish profile. We encrypt this value on a per-user/per-machine basis. So if you take the same file to a different machine (*or if a different user logged into the same machine*) it would not decrypt to the correct value. Because of this it's not worth investigating if you can decrypt the value which is stored by VS on a build server.

Comment: Ahhh what a shame... I believe in cases like this that CI is the *best* place to put this infoas being able to test what your CI server is doing it pretty critical to avoid any CI/CD friction.

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/03/27/continuous-integration-ndash-itrsquos-all-about-your-build-projects-ecosystem

P.s thanks for being awesome and answering!

Comment: So, after reading another of your posts Sayed, I should be passing it on the command line? This feels a little "code smelly" to me.

Comment: Late to the party here, @Doug, but you can store msdeploy password in Windows Credential Manager and use the `getCredential` parameter of msdeploy (unsupported by the msbuild tasks though)

Comment: Interesting. If you're following the "build server holds the keys" model that's a really nice hack - although the publish profile has no way to include that.

Comment: Trying to automate publishing with msbuild, wanting to use credentials saved by Visual Studio (on the same machine and user), but so far that seems impossible? @Sayed am I right that this isn't supported, and if so where do I file a bug report (or is Microsoft actually recommending use of clear-string passwords on the commandline?)

Comment: @nikize you can report it using Report a Problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017